# how to test a view that calls fetch on a collection in its constructor?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, sinon, chai, karma-mocha

I have a BackboneView which I pass a collection upon creation

```
  var my_collection = new Collection();
  new MyView({temp: template, collection: my_collection });
```

Inside the view, the fetch() method is called on the collection in the constructor like this

```
export class MyView extends Backbone.View {

    constructor(options){

      this.collection = options.collection;
      super();
      this.collection.fetch().done(function(resp){
      that.render();
      })
    }
    render(){
    }

}
```

I had (past tense) a series of tests that tested the UI/template of the View like this

```
  describe('testing my view', function() {
    it('should have one main child - div 6 ', function() {
      expect(myview.el.children.length).to.equal(1);
    });
  });
```

However, since I have now added code that passed the collection to the view, and called the fetch method on the collection in the constructor, all of my tests fail because the view tries to call the fetch method every time I run the tests. Even if I pass a stub collection, I have to set a `url`and the view will try to fetch on the stub collection resulting in a 404

```
 var gs = class StubCollection extends Backbone.Collection{

   constructor(options){
    this.url = '/blah';
   }
 }

  const drv =   new MyView({temp: template, collection: new gs()});
```

I need to call fetch on the collection in the view (i.e. I can't not use that code). How can I continue to test the view in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stub the `fetch` method itself. Inside `StubCollection` define it as:

```
function fetch() {
    return $.Deferred().resolve().promise();
}
```

According to the [Backbone's documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch), `fetch` returns a [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) which represents the request that is sent.

jqXHR is a Promise, which is an object that represents an ongoing process that may either succeed or fail, and has methods called `done` and `fail` for registering callbacks to be called when it succeeds or fails, respectively. (jqXHR succeeds if the request is successful and fails it could not be sent or the server returned an error code).

In the above code, we manually create a [Deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) (used to create promises), and immediately change its state to successful (with `resolve`). Then we return its promise. Because the promise is immediately considered successful, the `done` callback will be called immediately.

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you update your answer or add a comment to include an example how to mock  `Backbone.save()` in a similar way (I'm running into a similar problem)

Comment: @Leahcim You can stub the model's `sync` method (which makes the request) to emulate the server returning a hash of the changed attributes: `function sync(method, model, options) { return $.Deferred().resolve(options.attrs || model.toJSON(options)).promise(); }`

Answer (score 2):

Not the easiest solution, but in the long term definitely the best:
**You shouldn't call `fetch` on a collection from a view.**

A view really has no business telling a collection or model what to do. A view only presents data and/or captures user input. The call for loading said data should be someplace else. Depending on what paradigm you like to follow this could be in a controller or command.
It will make testing a lot easier, since your views will be more system agnostic, i.e. they have less knowledge of what's happening when.
Views, models, collections and services should always be as dumb as possible: it's easier to test, reuse, extend and modify.
All application-specific code should go into your controllers and commands. I.e. they are the glue that combine your application agnostic views, models and services into the specific application your working on.